# How to do pagination using apex and LWC without using OFFSET or WHERE clause to showcase records

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql, governorlimits, pagination

I want the logic to be in apex. QueryLocator, queryMore etc have limited application seen with reference to this.

I am currently trying to query all the records and slice them accordingly. But, this seems to have an affect on memory.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to explain what you have tried and where you are stuck. It is important to show the latter, or at least explain your research, since without this your question is likely to be closed without answer. This community is not a free coding service but rather are here to help with specific technical issues. Additionally, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You need to explain why you think you cannot use `OFFSET` and/or `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: I do not want to use OFFSET or WHERE clause as they have their limitations. OFFSET will not work if the value is more than 2000 while WHERE clause seems to be tedious.

Comment: Using WHERE clause will make my SOQL more like [.....WHERE ID> :previousID] for fetching next set of records. But how could I get the  next or previous IDs?

Comment: Well, sorry to break it to you, but to do pagination you have to have a means to 1. Continue from where you left off and 2. Actually keep the query bounded to avoid governor limit issues (you can only query up to 50000 records in normal transactions against the org). Why is 2000 such a problem (max OFFSET)? Do you really expect a user to scroll through more than this in the UI? If they have that much data to look at the user experience will be terrible and they need a way to filter down the number of records to look at.

Comment: @PhilW, okay Thank you so much for your inputs. :)

Comment: In case I want to do pagination for 5000 records, then I am writing my query as [SELECT ID, NAME, PHONE FROM ACCOUNT LIMIT :(pageNumber*pageSize)]. But this would cause a trouble on the memory. Can I please get a solution for this?

Comment: My solution would be to support filtering and stop pagination at 2000 records in, showing a message to the user telling them to filter the records as there are too many to show. If you are using pagination showing 50 records at a time, they are going to have to press "Next" 40 times to get to the point here LIMIT has a problem. Do you really think someone is going to really do that and expect to continue pressing "Next" to see yet more data they are probably not even really looking at?

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by simply passing n number of records to UI the first time when they click next then you should update the next records in the same variable and you can do this further. The same thing you can follow by decreasing the same n number of records when they click the back button, but must check whether we have n records or not. You can use the below code for reference.

HTML code

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <template for:each={displayedTiles} for:item="tile">
            <div key={tile.id} class="tile">{tile.label}</div>
        </template>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
        <lightning-button-group>
            <lightning-button label="Previous" onclick={handlePrevious} disabled={disablePrevious}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button label="Next" onclick={handleNext} disabled={disableNext}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-button-group>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS Code

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class PaginationDemo extends LightningElement {
    @track tiles = []; // Array of all tiles
    @track displayedTiles = []; // Array of tiles to display
    @track currentPage = 1;
    @track pageSize = 8;
    
    connectedCallback() {
        // Initialize tiles data (20 tiles in this example)
        for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            this.tiles.push({ id: i, label: `Tile ${i}` });
        }
        // Initial display of tiles
        this.displayTiles();
    }
    
    displayTiles() {
        const startIndex = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.pageSize;
        const endIndex = startIndex + this.pageSize;
        this.displayedTiles = this.tiles.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
    
    get disablePrevious() {
        return this.currentPage === 1;
    }
    
    get disableNext() {
        return this.currentPage === Math.ceil(this.tiles.length / this.pageSize);
    }
    
    handlePrevious() {
        if (!this.disablePrevious) {
            this.currentPage--;
            this.displayTiles();
        }
    }
    
    handleNext() {
        if (!this.disableNext) {
            this.currentPage++;
            this.displayTiles();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: But, I don't want to pass the records in frontEnd. The logic has to be in apex

Comment: Why you don't want to use offset? any reason?

Comment: @BhavyaManjushaC You can use 'NOT IN' and from front end pass those ids which you already got earlier, by this way you will not get the repeated records again.(But yes it's not good approach)

Comment: I don't want to use offset as I might have to skip 2k records in the future. My intention is to know if there are any other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As there are limitations when using OFFSET in apex as follows.

**The maximum offset is 2,000 rows. Requesting an offset greater than 2,000 results in a NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE error.**

If pagination needs to be used in the REST-API Inbound without OFFSET with more than 10k records, there must be a unique key where we can sort the records by ASC or DESC

```
//If pageNumber is 1 - directly return first pageSize records
query += ' LIMIT :queryLimit ASC';

if(pageNumber > 1){
    Integer firstRecordNumber = (pageNo-1)*pageSize;
    Integer lastRecordNumber = ((pageNo-1)*pageSize) + pageSize;
    for(sObject obj : [ALL RECORDS SORTED]){
        if(iterator < firstRecordNumber){
            iterator += 1;
            continue;
        }
        if(iterator > lastRecordNumber){
            break; //As you reached last record
        }
        //Process your obj record for sending it in resonse
        iterator += 1;
    }
}
```

It involves iterating over all the records and might increase the CPU limit as well as memory if there are large number of records.